# Any way to organize YouTube subscriptions into categories?

Tags: youtube

With a growing number of channel subscriptions, I find it more and more annoying to browse my subscriptions list in search for new videos. I was wondering if there is any way to organize all the channels I have subscribed to into categories (such as comedy, science, gaming, et c.). YouTube used to have that functionality in the form of *collections*, but that feature was [discontinued](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6233832). Is there any other way to better organize your subscriptions?

If there is no way to do this using YouTube's tools itself, I would also be interested in any third-party app or service that offers that functionality, as long as it's free. I have only found a service called Videodeck so far, but it's freemium and I'm not paying for something that should be a basic functionality of YouTube itself in my opinion.

Comment: I suggest you remove your second paragraph. We don't accept requests for app recommendations here. (For that, go to [softwarerecs.se].) If you leave it your question may be closed. See also: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354)